# Binding a combobox in subform Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, subforms

I have a subform which has the correct Source Object, Link Master field and Link Child field parameters.

I can create a combobox in the subform which shows the correct information in the drop down menu (same table as the source object of the subform), but is **unbound** and does not update the record in the main form.

Does anyone know how this might be fixed?

(note the relationship between Master and Child is over multiple tables, but has referential integrity and cascade updates enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the combo is on a subform is not relevant in this case. The wizard will set everything for you, but the rule for binding a control is to set the `Control Source`. For example, your subform contains a list of places by PlaceID and you wish to update it using a combo that shows the user a list of place names in a combo.

```
 Control Source: PlaceID
 Row Source    : SELECT ID, PlaceName FROM Places ORDER BY PlaceName
 Bound Column  : 1
 Column Count  : 2
 Column Widths : 0; 2cm
```

[image: A combo on a subform]

The relationships

[image: relationships for the tables]

Comment: Sounds promising: unfortunately, when I select Control source to be the ID of the Master field the combobox will automatically display this number, and although the other information from the SQL query will be technically available, it will refuse anything other than the ID of the Master field as a valid parameter. :-( I normally would do a trial and error thing of (well what about the source ID as Control Source?) but I cannot see how that could work as it would in that case be entirely unrelated to the Master field; thereby negating the point of the combobox in the first place...

Comment: You would never set a combobox to be the ID of the master field. You would rarely display the master field in a subform, because it is completed automatically by virtue of being a master field.

Comment: In the illustration, ID in the Places table is PlaceID in the PlacesPersons junction (join) table. It is a convention. PersonID is filled in automatically.

Comment: Afraid it's displaying a dialogue box saying: Invalid Control Property: Control Source ... No Such Field in the Field List.      There is definitely no typo with the Control Property I've set, though.

Comment: If it is not available in the control source drop down of field names, then it is not available on the form. Check the record source of your subform and ensure that the field is included.